# Accessing Methods from Classes in pyQT

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a small GUI with two simple buttons to access a LabJAck IO module.  This module is used to turn on or turn off an external device connected to it.  I have written a class that inits the device and several methods to do some things with the device two of which are, turn on and turn off.  The reason I am going about accessing the LAbJack this way is because I would like the code to be nice and neat and I will have several devices connected to my machine with each device having specific IO commands.

Here is my code for the LabJAck:

```
import u3

class LabJack:
    def __init__(self):

        try:
            self.Switch = u3.U3()
        except:
            print "Labjack Error"

        #Define State Registers for RB12 Relay Card

        self.Chan0 = 6008
        Chan1 = 6009
        Chan2 = 6010
        Chan3 = 6011
        Chan4 = 6012
        Chan5 = 6013

    #Turn the channel on
    def IO_On(self,Channel):
        self.Switch.writeRegister(Channel,0)


    #Turn the channel off
    def IO_Off(self,Channel):   
        self.Switch.writeRegister(Channel,1)

    #The State of the Channel
    def StateSetting(self,Channel):
        self.Switch.readRegister(Channel)
        if Switch.readRegister(Channel) == 0:
            print ('Channel is On')
        else:
            print('Channel is Off')

    #Direction of Current Flow
    def CurrentDirection(self,Channel):
        self.Switch.readRegister(6108)
        print self.Switch.readRegister(6108)
```

Here is my GUI Code:

```
import re
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
from LabJackIO import *
from Piezo902 import *

import ui_aldmainwindow

class ALDMainWindow(QMainWindow,ui_aldmainwindow.Ui_ALDMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ALDMainWindow,self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.ValveControl = LabJack()

        self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(self.ValveControl.IO_On(6008))
       self.Valve_OFF.clicked.connect(self.ValveControl.IO_Off(self.ValveControl.Chan0))
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Valve Off')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('motif')
form = ALDMainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

When running the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ALDSoftwareMainWindow.py", line 26, in <module>
    form = ALDMainWindow()
  File "ALDSoftwareMainWindow.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(self.ValveControl.IO_On(6008))
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'int'
```

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925241/send-additional-variable-during-pyqt-pushbutton-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Using `partial` maybe a best way.

```
self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.ValveControl.IO_on,6008))
```

2 Use `QSignalMapper`.

Comment: How do you add a self.statusBar().showMessage() to be executed after the Valve_On/Off.clicked.connect as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method you are connecting the button to:

```
self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(self.ValveControl.IO_On(6008))
```

Probably this will fix your problem:

```
self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ValveControl.IO_On(6008))
```

`lambda` is an anonymous function that will defer the calling of your method `IO_ON(6008)` until the button is actually clicked.

Comment: this will work in this case, but beware of tricksy closure traps.

Comment: Like what?. I like tricksy closure traps while I do serious things, I don't know about you.(damn the minimum post length requirement).

Comment: See the question linked in my answer.  I was doing something like this, but I was generating the `lambda`s from values in a list and ended up only binding the _last_ value of the list.

Comment: and to be clear, I meant traps for you, not traps in the code ;)

Comment: How do you add a self.statusBar().showMessage() to be executed after the Valve_On/Off.clicked.connect as well? – Vivek Dwivedi

Comment: If I understand you right, that you want 2 handlers for the Valve_ON button, then you just connect the button to all the handlers you want executed and they will be in turn self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage('Hello World'))

Answer (score 1):

You have mis-uderstood how slots/signals work.  The argument to `connect` needs to be a *function* that takes as an argument what ever the signal you are connecting to emits.  In this case, it looks like you are connecting to `clicked` signal from a button (which emits no values).  So you need to wrap the function you want to call in a function that takes no arguments.  An easy way to do this is to wrap the functions in `lambda` function:

```
self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(lmabda x=6008: self.ValveControl.IO_On(x))
self.Valve_OFF.clicked.connect(lambda x=self.ValveControl.Chan0: self.ValveControl.IO_Off(x))
```

which creates functions with one optional argument (which defaults the values you want) so it will work as a no-argument slot.

It may seem odd to use the default argument to bind the value in, but it prevents some strange seeming issues with closures (see [Python lambda closure scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355233/python-lambda-closure-scoping))

Another way is to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to wrap your functions.